# How do I hide UIView and make it appear when an area is tapped on screen in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm building a Video player. I added a controlsContainer UIView (that contains custom playback controls) on top of a UIView I used for my AVPlayerLayer. How do I make this controlsContainer view to always hide after few seconds of appearing and only reappear when an area of the AVPlayerLayer is tapped just like the YouTube iOS App's video player?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looking into using a timer and a tap gesture?

Answer (score 0):

Add touch events to AVplayerLayer and when the user touches the player unhide it for say 5 secs and after 5 secs hide it.If you want you can add the animation for hiding and unhiding.

or
If you are using avplayerviewcontroller directly you can simply say
showPlayBackControls=true;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your container view is on top of your video layer add a tap gesture recognizer to your view and keep track of whether are not your controls are showing.  When the state changes animate the change.  Here I just set all the subviews alpha to do a fade in/out but you can just as easily set the transform to have a slide in out instead.  When the control appears on screen you set a count down timer and have the timer turn the controls off.  You could also keep a reference to this timer and then cancel it and reschedule it each time the user interacts with the ui, which is probably better than what I have here, but you get the idea.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        weak var controlView: UIView!
        var isHidingControls = false

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            controlView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapControls)))
        }
        func tapControls() {
            isHidingControls = !isHidingControls
            animateControls()
        }
        func animateControls() {
            if isHidingControls {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    self.controlView.subviews.forEach {$0.alpha = 0}
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.controlView.subviews.forEach {$0.isHidden = true}
                })
            } else {
                self.controlView.subviews.forEach {$0.isHidden = true}
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    self.controlView.subviews.forEach {$0.alpha = 1}
                }, completion: { _ in
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
                        guard self?.isHidingControls == false else {
                            return
                        }
                        self?.isHidingControls = true
                        self?.animateControls()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```